# The following program that was meant to solve a quadratic equation: [ax²+bx+c=0]. What problems with the above code can you spot?

Tags: python, syntax, syntax-error, quadratic-programming

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYxNx.png)

> ```
> a, b, c = input() 
> d = b*b - 4ac 
> if d > 0:
>   print(+sqrt(d)-b/(2a))
>   print(-sqrt(d)-b/(2a)) 
> else:
> print("No real roots")
> ```

This question is from an online python practice sample. I am new to learning python and also tried writing the same program in the code editor and it says no many syntax errors. Help!

Comment: Hi, 
There are multiple mistakes in the code you shared. You are directly using algebraic notations like "4ac" which should actually be "4 * a * c". Please start with simple Hello World programs at first and then move on to more complex ones.

Comment: @SwastikMohapatra This is a question from my test paper

Answer (score 0):

Here would be a running solution, but as the other user in the command pointed out it would be better to start slowly and understand the concepts better

```
try:
    inputs=(input("Type in 3 consecutive numbers seperated with spaces:").split() )
    a,b,c = map(int, inputs)
except ValueError:
    print("This is not a whole number.")

d = b*b - 4*a*c 
if d > 0:
    print(+sqrt(d)-b/(2*a))
    print(-sqrt(d)-b/(2*a)) 
else:
    print("No real roots")
```

Comment: then you need to convert your a,b,c - variables to integer values  - because the input() funciton only returns a string

Comment: Can we use this for input "a, b, c = map(int, input("Enter three values: ").split())"

Answer (score 0):

After few tweaks, this program works as intended.

```
a, b, c = map(int, input("Enter three values: ").split())
d = b*b - 4*a*c
if d > 0:
    print(+sqrt(d)-b/(2*a))
    print(-sqrt(d)-b/(2*a))
else:
    print("No real roots")
```